# html publisher jenkins error, directory exists but failed copying to another folder path.

Tags: jenkins, newman

[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\firstpostman to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\firstpostman\htmlreports\HTML_20Report
ERROR: Directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\firstpostman' exists but failed copying to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\firstpostman\htmlreports\HTML_20Report'.
Finished: FAILURE

i havent specified any folder in HTML directory to archive as if i specify it gives another error folder not found.

please guide how to generate html report, i am using newman-jenkins.

Comment: Can you share the newman command which you have used to execute. My guess is you have used newman run <collectionname> -r <htmlname.html> for the default reports archive directory and lack of write permissions to the folder is what causing the issue.

Comment: @Maddy, See my answer, it can help: stackoverflow.com/a/54203222/5770004

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me the Windows Batch command was failing at some point. Apparently it is still trying to generate the HTML report but then it fails.

When the Windows Batch command is running correctly (result = 0) the HTML report is generated correctly.

Maybe you can try to simplify the Windows Batch command and try if the report will generate and copy to the Jenkins server.